# TypeError: n.easing[this.easing] is not a function jQuery not working

Tags: jquery, wordpress, jquery-ui, easing, jquery-easing

I'm developing this website: http://www.siraryf.com and there is a problem in the responsive version for mobile phones.

jQuery works good in normal version but for mobile phones stop working and then `TypeError: n.easing[this.easing] is not a function` error appears in the console. I have tried to use jQueryUI after jQuery with all the new versions, also I have tried to add jQuery easing "jquery.easing.1.3.js" and added with:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
// jquery.easing.1.3.js code goes here
});
```

but it still not working. Now I have tried another option with `jquery-migrate.min.js?ver=1.2.1` but it is still not working!

I'm using Wordpress btw.

Comment: i'm not sure you have to check easing supportable in your mobile browser

Comment: Hey did you ever solve this one? I am having the exact same problem with my Wordpress site. Can't get Jquery to work in the mobile view.

Answer (score 0):

For those who may still wonder, I had the same issue:

[image]

The problem was with WP plugin that was loading some very weird scripts. Including a duplicate copy of jQuery. Even in functions.php when I turned off all WP jQuery libraries, they were still loading. After turning off the plugin everything worked great with all versions of jQuery. I thought maybe with the update of either jQuery or WP something changed, but no, it was a plugin called WP Bannerize.